# Disable right click on image in email client

Tags: javascript, image, email

Is there a way to disable right clicking on an image in gmail? I'm aware of methods to do so using javascript, but only for an entire page. Is it possible to embed jscript into the body of an email and have it parsed?

Comment: Please consider that sending an email containing a `<script>` may be marked as _malicious_

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape the image out no matter what you do, so if you want to "disable" right clicking you could just put the image under a transparent div.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in html email. CSS position and negative margins are not widely supported, so you can't hide it under another transparent element.

Even if you embed the image using base64, it still right-clicks to download it.